# Insert or search a word with a punctuation mark ( ’ ) in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to Insert or search a word with a punctuation mark ( ’ ) in Snowflake.

I need to search and insert text ==>`CHILDREN'S CLINIC-New York`
for example, these are throwing errors:

```
-- 1 
select distinct CATEGORY FROM    "CATEGORY_MASTER" 
where CATEGORY = 'CHILDREN'S CLINIC-New York'

-- 2
INSERT INTO "CATEGORY_MASTER"  (id, "CATEGORY_MASTER" ) 
VALUES (1,CHILDREN'S CLINIC-New York)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is including a single quote in a string.  The SQL standard is to use two single quotes:

```
WHERE CATEGORY = 'CHILDREN''S CLINIC-New York'
```

Comment: thanks for the responses,i am trying to insert 1 row, but there are 50 rows and i need to Insert only 1 row, Is there any way to insert just 1 row or changing existing row to $$CHILDREN'S CLINIC-New York$$ with copy or insert statement

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$$...$$` to quote string literal:

> [Dollar-Quoted String Constants](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#dollar-quoted-string-constants)
>
> When a string contains many quote characters, it may be simpler to enclose string constants in dollar signs rather than single quote characters. A dollar-quoted string constant consists of the characters in the string surrounded by a pair of dollar signs ($$).

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY 
FROM "CATEGORY_MASTER" 
WHERE CATEGORY = $$CHILDREN'S CLINIC-New York$$;

INSERT INTO "CATEGORY_MASTER"  (id, "CATEGORY_MASTER" ) 
VALUES (1,$$CHILDREN'S CLINIC-New York$$);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e15661fe0daa97cfdb425e300ecbd950)**

---

Another alternative is to escape `'` with `\'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY 
FROM "CATEGORY_MASTER" 
WHERE CATEGORY = 'CHILDREN\'S CLINIC-New York';
```